# Como faço para somar em vez de concatenar

Tags: javascript, script

gostaria de uma ajuda.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 var totalBruto = 0;
        var tot_desconto_vlr = 0;
        var total = 0;
        var totalLiquido = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".desc_vlr").on("input", function () {
                totalBruto = $("#tot_bruto").val();
                tot_desconto_vlr = $(this).val();

                total = totalBruto + tot_desconto_vlr;
                console.info(total);

               var tot_liquido = $(this).attr("desconto");

                $("#" + tot_liquido).val(total);
            });
        });
```

Em vez de somar, ele ta concatenando exemplo: 2 + 2 = 22

Gostaria de saber o que eu to fazendo de errado para pode somar em vez de concatenar.

Desde já, obrigado !!

Comment: Basicamente `.val()` retorna uma String. Tens de usar `parseFloat`, `Number` ou `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele acha que você tem um string.
Tenta :

```
total = parseInt(totalBruto) + parseInt(tot_desconto_vlr);
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo esta somando, mas ele ta arredondando também, exemplo:  29.25 se eu informa 1, ele arredonda pra 30 ignorando as cadas decimais. Sabe como resolver?

Comment: total = parseFloat(totalBruto) + parseFloat(tot_desconto_vlr);